# bash script to move or copy file to a Dest folder containing Today's Date folder in it

Tags: linux, bash

I need help to write a script to move or copy file to a Destination folder containing Today's Date folder in it. If there is no Today's Date folder inside Destination folder, then, it should create a folder and then move the file.

Example:

- Source Folder = `\home\A\`
- Destination Folder = `\home\Dest\`

Assume a file `abc.txt` in source folder. This file should be moved to Today's date folder inside the Dest folder. i.e; `\home\Dest\20140606\abc.txt`

Note: DateFormat for Today's Date folder = `YYYYMMDD`

Comment: Can you show what you've tried so far? What specific part of this do you need help with?

Answer (score 0):

Create the directory using `mkdir` and then use `cp` to copy the file to it.

```
dest=/home/Dest/$(date +%Y%m%d)
mkdir -p "$dest" && cp /home/A/abc.txt "$dest"
```

Comment: You should use ; rather than && on the mkir; else it will only work once a day. (or only do it conditionally..)

Comment: If I use `;` it will run `cp` even if `mkdir` fails which I don't want.

Comment: and `mkdir -p` works if the directory already exists, so it will work more than once a day.

Comment: good call; I never checked exit code with -p vs without; you get my vote.

Answer (score 0):

mkdir -p /home/Dest/`date +"%Y-%m-%d"`; mv /home/A/abc.txt /home/Dest/`date +"%Y-%m-%d"`/.

or in a shell script...

```
wom$>cat /tmp/bash.sh
dateDir=/home/Dest/`date +"%Y-%m-%d"`
if [ ! -d "${destDir}" ]; then
    echo mkdir -p ${dateDir}
    mkdir -p ${dateDir}
fi
echo mv $1 ${dateDir}/$1
mv $1 ${dateDir}/$1

wom$>/tmp/bash.sh abc
mkdir -p /home/Dest/2014-06-02
mv abc /home/Dest/2014-06-02/abc
```